# How to display array data in react-native-tableview in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I'm using react-native-tableview to display list of data.

Here's my code

```
    <TableView style = {styles.usersTableViewStyle}
                   allowsToggle={true}
                   allowsMultipleSelection={true}
                   tableViewStyle={TableView.Consts.Style.Plain}
                   tableViewCellStyle={TableView.Consts.CellStyle.Subtitle}
                   onPress={(event) => console.log(event)}>

             <Section label="List" style={styles.Section}>
                    <Item> Apple </Item>
                    ....
             </Section>

    </TableView>
```

Now a simple table with dummy data is coming.

I have **two** questions

1. I have one array and I want to display the entire content in table.  How can we achieve this?
2. Can't able to increase the row height, section height in css.  How to increase the cell height?

Anyhelp could be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this once https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tableview-simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer for my first question. **How to display array values in tableview?**

With this code we can display array values in react-native-tableview.

```
<TableView style = {styles.fruitsTableViewStyle}
               allowsToggle={true}
               allowsMultipleSelection={true}
               tableViewStyle={TableView.Consts.Style.Plain}
               tableViewCellStyle={TableView.Consts.CellStyle.Subtitle}
               onPress={(event) => console.log(event)}>

          <Section label = 'List'>
               {
                   fruitsArray.map(function(name, index) {
                        return <Item key = {index} label = {name}>
                                     {name}
                               </Item>
                        )
               }

          </Section>
</TableView>
```